# Decoction Weyermann Bohemian Pilsner vs Malte Pilsen Floor Bohemian

Tags: malt, lager, specialty-malt, base-malt

Im making a recipe to brew a czech lager,

im planning to do a triple decction mash, but i see many opinions about them.

It does not work as a decoction in Bohemian Pilsner because it is much modified. Do you test the comparison and see differences?

Will it make a difference to make it like Bohemian Pilsner? Because where I live I don't have access to the Floor Bohemian

Answer (score 2):

You can decoct with modern malts such as the standard Weyermann Bohemian Pilsner malt.  Just expect your efficiency and your attenuation to be very high, both with percentages in mid to upper 80s.

The modern Floor Malt is likewise highly modified.  I have struggled to find ANY widely available malt that is undermodified and thus suitable for decoction.  It would be a rare find in the 21st century -- there simply is not enough demand for it from modern brewers.  Brewers who are interested in decoction will tend to use Floor Malt... but what they likely do not realize is that it is nearly as highly modified as any other malt.

Comment: So, personally, I have decocted in the past, but I do not decoct any longer.  In my opinion, there is no good advantage to doing so, except as an experiment.  Flavor difference is undetectable by most or all -- if you ran a blind triangle test, you would not know the difference.  Decoction will darken a beer if desired.  Efficiency and attenuation will be high; however, *I* do not need these things to be higher than normal.  To each his own.